# How to clean up substrate runtime compiled result and compile again

Tags: substrate, polkadot

Now, The only way I used is  `cargo clean` and then `cargo build` again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also delete the `target` directory that contains all the build artifacts.

Comment: That's exactly what `cargo clean` does?

Comment: Indeed. Aside from deleting the build artifacts, how else do you wish to "clean up" Substrate and compile again?

Answer (score 0):

There's two way to have a clean compile:

1. Remove directory target with following command if you using Mac or Linux

   rm -rf target
2. Cargo clean and build with following command:

   cargo clean && cargo build --release